# JMeter TCP Sampler how to close connection

Tags: jmeter

I have to test TCP connection using JMeter. According to the Wireshark, the application sends 4 messages – 1st – for connection establishing and the next 3 for data sending (I think these 3 should re-use the connection of the 1st one).
I am using BinaryTCPClientImpl, Hex data in a text field. TCP samplers do not stop working.

I tried:

- Check Close connection check box
- Set up EOL equals to 10, 13, 24, 18, 128
- Set up tcp.BinaryTCPClient.eomByte equals to 0, 1 , 10, 18, 24, 122 in jmeter.prooperties file
- Set up timeout for response (in this case sampler finishes with 500 error - see below)

Response message is:

```
Sample Start: 2019-02-27 15:25:57 MSK

Load time: 9825

Connect Time: 2
Latency: 5
Size in bytes: 122
Sent bytes:0

Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 122
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: 

Response headers:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: windows-1251
```

Please, help me to fix it, I absolutely have no idea

Comment: Hex data finishes with "1f18", "12e2", "c067", " afe7"